# Using Ansible to update dynamic variables(ip's) in cassandra files while launching multiple ec2 instances in AWS at a time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, devops, cassandra-2.1

I am spining multiple ec2 instances in AWS and installing cassandra on those instances.
i got stucked up at updating ip addresses of those instances dynamically in the cassandra files.

I tried using set facts module to pass variables between different plays, it is updating the ip address of the last machine built out of the three ec2 instances in all the files.
My use case is to update the ip address in the file with regard to that ec2 instance.

```
###########################################################
Here is my playbook which consists of two plays:
#### Play1 - to spin 3 ec2 instances in AWS##########
- name: Play1
  hosts: local
  connection: local
  gather_facts: True
  vars:
    key_location: "path to pem file location"
    server_name: dbservers
    private_ip: item.private_ip
  tasks:
    - name: create ec2 instance
      ec2:
        key_name: {{ my_key_name}}
        region: us-east-1
        instance_type: t2.micro
        image: ami-8fcee4e5
        wait: yes
        group: {{ my_security_group_name}}
        count: 3 
        vpc_subnet_id: {{ my_subnet_id }}
        instance_tags:
          Name: devops-i-cassandra1-d-1c-common
          Stack: Ansible
          Owner: devops
      register: ec2

    - name: set facts ##  to capture the ip addresses of the ec2 instances, but only last ip is being captured
      set_fact:
        one_fact={{ item.private_ip }}
      with_items: ec2.instances

    - name: debugging private ip value
      debug: var=one_fact

    - name: Add the newly created EC2 instance(s) to the dbservers group in the inventory file
      local_action: lineinfile
                    dest="/home/admin/hosts"
                    regexp={{ item.private_ip }}
                    insertafter="[dbservers]" line={{ item.private_ip }}
      with_items: ec2.instances
    - name: Create Host Group to login dynamically to EC2 Instance
      add_host:
        hostname={{ item.private_ip }}
        groupname={{ server_name }}
        ansible_ssh_private_key_file={{ key_location }}
        ansible_ssh_user=ec2-user
        ec2_id={{ item.id }}
      with_items: ec2.instances

    - name: Wait for SSH to come up
      local_action: wait_for
                    host={{ item.private_ip }}
                    port=22
                    delay=60
                    timeout=360
                    state=started
      with_items: ec2.instances

####################Play2-Installing and Configuring Cassandra on Ec2 Instances
- name: Play2
  hosts: dbservers
  remote_user: ec2-user
  sudo: yes
  vars:
    private_ip: "{{ hostvars.localhost.one_fact }}"
  vars_files:
    - ["/home/admin/vars/var.yml"]
  tasks:
    - name: invoke a shell script to install cassandra
      script: /home/admin/cassandra.sh creates=/home/ec2-user/cassandra.sh

    - name: configure cassandra.yaml file
      template: src=/home/admin/cassandra.yaml dest=/etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml owner=ec2-user group=ec2-user mode=755
```

#

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

With ansible 2.0+, you refresh the dynamic inventory in the middle of the playbook as the task like this:

```
- meta: refresh_inventory
```

To extend this a bit, If you are getting problem with the cache in your playbook, then you can use it like this:

```
   - name: Refresh the ec2.py cache
     shell: "./inventory/ec2.py --refresh-cache"
     changed_when: no

   - name: Refresh inventory
     meta: refresh_inventory
```

where `./inventory` is the path to your dynamic inventory, please adjust it accordingly.

During the creation of your EC2 instances, you have added the tags to them, which you can use now with the dynamic inventory to configure these instances. Your second play will be like this:

```
- name: Play2
  hosts: tag_Name_devops-i-cassandra1-d-1c-common
  remote_user: ec2-user
  sudo: yes
  tasks:
   - name: ---------
```

Hope this will help you.